# Unable to View Recordsets in Access Form Listbox using NextRecordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I’m using the `NEXTRECORDSET` method to view the records generated from a SQL stored procedure.  The SP takes the user input and searches 3 tables in a SQL database and returns those records which contain the value(s) to Access.  I'm able to successfully see the results in my debug (`debug.print`) window in Access, but not in the Listbox `lstResults1` or all 3 listboxes of an Access form.  The form procedure that calls the function and the function itself is below.   I was able to successfully pass the resultset to the Listboxes (`lstResults1`, `lstResults2`, etc.) in the form by substituting the `rstCompound` statement in the Function with a loop for each Recordset (see third code sample) but it wasn't as clean and I was getting an "Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set", every time one of the values I searched for was in the second or third tables:

PROCEDURE

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()
'On Error Resume Next

    Dim strSQL As String

    'Stored procedure + parameters called from form
    strSQL = "Exec spSQL_SearchDatabase " & "'" & Me.txtTables & "'" & _
        ", " & "'%" & Me.txtSearchTerm & "%'"

    OpenMyRecordset rstCompound, strSQL

    Set Me.lstResults1.Recordset = rstCompound

    'debug - view procedure
    Me.lblQuery.Caption = strSQL
    Me.Repaint

End Sub
```

FUNCTION

```
Public Function OpenMyRecordset(rstCompound As ADODB.Recordset, strSQL As String, _
    Optional rrCursor As rrCursorType, _
    Optional rrLock As rrLockType, Optional bolClientSide As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset

    If con.STATE = adStateClosed Then
        con.ConnectionString = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=vnysql;DSN=RecordsMgmt_SQLDB;UID=DMP;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=RecordsManagementDB;"
        con.Open
    End If


    Set rstCompound = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rstCompound
        .ActiveConnection = con
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = IIf((rrCursor = 0), adOpenDynamic, rrCursor)
        .LockType = IIf((rrLock = 0), adLockOptimistic, rrLock)
        .Open strSQL
    End With

    ' Display results from each recordset
    intCount = 1
    Do Until rstCompound Is Nothing
        Debug.Print "Contents of recordset #" & intCount

        Do Until rstCompound.EOF
            Debug.Print rstCompound.Fields(0), rstCompound.Fields(1)
            rstCompound.MoveNext
        Loop

        Set rstCompound = rstCompound.NextRecordset
        intCount = intCount + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

Substituted Statement in Function

```
 Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs1
        .ActiveConnection = con
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = IIf((rrCursor = 0), adOpenDynamic, rrCursor)
        .LockType = IIf((rrLock = 0), adLockOptimistic, rrLock)
        .Open strSQL
   End With

    Do Until rs1.EOF
       Debug.Print rs1.Fields(0), rs1.Fields(1)
            rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

   Set rs2 = rs1.NextRecordset
    Do Until rs1.EOF
       Debug.Print rs2.Fields(0), rs2.Fields(1)
            rs2.MoveNext
    Loop

   Set rs3 = rs2.NextRecordset

   Do Until rs3.EOF
       Debug.Print rs3.Fields(0), rs3.Fields(1)
            rs3.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Function OpenMyRecordset never sets anything to return.  It needs something like

```
Set OpenMyRecordset = rstCompound
```

Also, with all the debug statements rstCompound  may be at EOF and have nothing to show.